# Change ActionScript source code from SWF File

Tags: actionscript-3, converters, flash, fla

First of all, I have only the swf file, I want to make some changes on ActionScript of it, i want to know, if I convert my swf file into fla, can I edit my actionscript with Abdobe flash professional CS ? Is it possible to convert an swf file into fla ?

Thanks.

Comment: You can do it as gPeart suggested with a decompiler like the one from Sothink, but if it's complex project it will be hard to read because the decompiler does not return the original variable, constant or function names. Don't quote me on that, though, it's been a while since I needed a decompiler.

If the class exported by the decompiler is called `Main`, then you do this in the first frame: `addChild(new Main())`. Off the top of my head, should start the whole thing just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have the source file (AS files or FLA) used to create the SWF file, you have 2 options, use a SWF decompiler or [as3swf](https://github.com/claus/as3swf) (Low level Actionscript 3 library to parse, create, modify and publish SWF files). 
You will not be able to convert with all details, but is a good try.

Tutorial how to use a [Document Class](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-a-document-class-in-flash--active-3233)

Comment: I used a decompiler "Sothink SWF Quicker" , it gives me all the as files, I made the changes I want, but to compile them in a single Swf File, is the problem ... I'll try the as3wsf, it seems great if it modifies the actionscript, and keep the swf extension, I'll give it a try

Comment: if you have all AS file you can create a new FLA to load a main AS file and export the new SWF

Comment: Using Abode flash professional CS3, I opened the Main.as file, but I could not find how to export it into swf ...

Comment: I have added a link on my answer, so you can 'learn' how to use a document class.

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial, I created a new fla file, on the same folder of the Main.as file, then I linked the fla file to the Main file, by writing : Main on the Document class field. When publishing it into swf format, it shows only the Main.as file, why the other files were not published also ?

Comment: It's too vague to be able to understand all details. A SWF of the linked Main.as will contain everything that Main.as file is using (instances, classes, etc), and will be published in only one .SWF file.

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't make myself clear, So what I was trying to say is when I published SWF file, the content of it was about 1 ko, I used Sothink Again to view the content of the SWF file, it shows me only the Main.as file, on my decompiled "actionscripts" there are a lot of AS files, with multiples folders.